# How to click on QTextEdit with cursor in PyQT5 code

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a QTextEdit acting as a input field of sorts so whenever you click the post button, it posts whatever is in that QTextEdit. However after I hit post, the text edit deselects which is annoying to have to keep clicking on it before I type more. Is there a method or way in PyQT5 to click on that text box automatically in my code without having to manually move my mouse?

I looked into QTextCursor but that appears to be more for the actual text inside of the text box instead of the box itself. If there's a way to do this, I would greatly appreciate it, thank you!

Comment: Set the [focus-policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop) of the post button to `Qt.NoFocus`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.